# VSTO Visio 2010 Handling MarkerEvent

Tags: c#, vsto, visio

I'm trying to handle the MarkerEvent, however I get a compliation error saying my method doesn't match the delegate.

```
Application.MarkerEvent += new Visio.EApplication_MarkerEventEventHandler(Application_MarkerEvent);
//...
private void Application_MarkerEvent(Visio.Application application, int sequence, int context)
    {
    }
```

Basically, I copied that method signature from the Visio 2010 SDK that had a VB example though.

The point of writing that code is to handle the doubleclick event on a shape. I'm open to your suggestion on how I can do it in a different way. However, I just read only about that MarkerEvent thing on the Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff765486.aspx), the last parameter is a string.

So:

```
private void Application_MarkerEvent(Visio.Application application,
     int sequence, string context)
{
}
```

But you *should* also just be able to use `+=`<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>

Comment: Hi Mark! Thanks a lot! It works now. I really overlooked that I had the last parameter as an int. Anyway, originally it was an int, but the second one was a long that also caused an error despite the documentation said it should be a long. I guess, C# and VB have different longs.

Comment: Marc sorry for misspelling your name at first.

Comment: @Mike no hard feelings; frankly you get used to it ;p